# Python script, syntax error, invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following python script which i want to run..
However, it keeps showing the error message on my command prompt whenever i attempt to run the script.
Error message:

```
File "xor.py", line 9
               File = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read<>
               SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax
```

The following is the command i executed in cmd:

```
python xor.py sample_output.txt 'what would the secret be?'
```

The following is the script:

```
# xor.py
import sys
from itertools import cycle
file = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read()
string = sys.argv[2]
sys.stdout.write(''.join(chr(ord(x)^ord(y)) for (x,y) in zip(file, cycle(string))))
```

Comment: Code has `file = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read()` but the error says `File = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read()`. Why?

Comment: Please do not shadow builtins with variables, `file` and `string` are both bad choices for variable names.

Comment: Add the exact code you are running; if this is the code you are running - delete the file named `xor.pyc` (it will be in the same directory as `xor.py`) and try it again.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid What if he is not using CPython? ;)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Since the code has a syntax error, there would not be a .pyc file, as it can't be compiled.

Comment: Although sometimes with minor changes I found the `.pyc` doesn't get regenerated. If he introduced the error, fixed it, and the minor change wasn't picked up (`.pyc` wasn't regenerated), it could be why he is seeing the error when the code doesn't have it.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: How small or big the changes are makes no difference to if the .pyc-file gets regenerated or not.

Comment: I believe you; but its what I have experienced.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid No it's not. It's what you *think* you have experienced. The pyc-file get's recreated if the .py file is modified after the pyc-file. Also, it does *not* get (re)created if you run the .py file as the main file. I can't tell you why the .pyc file didn't get recreated, but trust me, it's not because the change was minor.

Answer (score 1):

You are not running the code you are editing, instead you are running a different file than the one you edited.

This is because there is no syntax error in the code that you have provided. However, there is a syntax error in the code in the error message:

```
File = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read<>
```

This ends with `<>`, not with `()`. I assumed this to be a transcription error, but you say that the error message really appears like this, although the code does not.

Hence: You are running a different file than the one you are editing.

Comment: It doesn't work on my side though. I keep getting the error message.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: No, I've several times encountered cases when people get errors that I don't get, and usually when they try again they don't get it either. When the problem doesn't exist, it's a valid answer to point this out. However, perhaps the error message is correct?

Comment: The script is included with read(). But the error message appears read<>

Comment: @LennartRegebro Is there something wrong with my command or? I'm still slightly lost...

Comment: @WeezelTan Yes, you are running a different file than the one you are editing. Ie you run the editor with `python foobar.py` but editing `frotz.py`.

Comment: @WeezelTan No, **I** ran the code you provided above. **You** are not running that code, because that code **works**. You must be running *another file*. A file that has a syntax error. This really is not a complicated concept.

Comment: @WeezelTan: See your comment on the other answer: *"Noted that but in the script it was .read(). The error message appeared .read<>"* Why do you think that is? Do you really think Python will change the syntax f your code in the error message about a syntax error?

Comment: @LennartRegebro Command ran was "python xor.py sample_output.txt'what would the secret be?' More or less get your explanation but xor.py does contains the code above. How could i be running another file?

Comment: @WeezelTan: You are obviously running `xor.py`. But that is not the file you are **editing**. Perhaps you are editing a file in a different directory, or with subtly different filename. Try changing the command to `more xor.py` to see what it really contains. Change the code to include a different syntax error, first in the file. The fact is: The code you provided does not result in the error message you claim. **Hence, you are not running a file with that code.** What you actually are doing we can only guess. But you are not running the file you think/claim that you are running.

Answer (score 0):

You have `.read<>` when you probably intended `.read()`

Comment: Noted that but in the script it was .read(). The error message appeared .read<>

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "file" is already reserved; that is built-in keyword so unable to set as the name of variable. 
And second, do not use <> instead of (). incorrect in grammar.

The problems might be clearly solved if you code like:

fd = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read()